# Add <script> to specific drupal page 6.19

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-6

I am completely new to Drupal and I just want to add this script to specific page/node on Drupal 6.19 I tried JS Injector module but it's not supporting Drupal 6.19 version, please someone help on this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
        var google_conversion_id = xxxxxxxxxx;
        var google_conversion_language = "en";
        var google_conversion_format = "3";
        var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
        var google_conversion_label = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
        var google_conversion_value = 0;
        var google_remarketing_only = false;
    /* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
    <div style="display:inline;">
        <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1071757202/?value=0&amp;label=qfCPCM691AYQku-G_wM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
    </div>
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the template.php file of your theme and search the **phptemplate_preprocess_page** function.

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if(drupal_get_path_alias() == 'your path') {
    drupal_add_js(base_path().path_to_theme()."/yourjsfile.js"); 
  }
}
```

In your Javascript file, you can add your custom script.

Regards.